# Displying large image in android and zooming

Tags: android, zooming, pinch

I use the code below to display a large bitmap(5000x 3000) which works fine but i cant for the life of me get the pinch and zoom working

Basically I want to load the image from the SD Card display it and then zoom in so that i can see the detail

Has anyone got any ideas?

Mark

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
   private static final String TAG = "Touch";
   // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

   // We can be in one of these 3 states
   static final int NONE = 0;
   static final int DRAG = 1;
   static final int ZOOM = 2;
   int mode = NONE; 

   // Remember some things for zooming
   PointF start = new PointF();
   PointF mid = new PointF();
   float oldDist = 1f;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ImageView jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.jpgview);
        String myJpgPath = "/sdcard/Datafiles/Images/DSC_3509.JPG"; //UPDATE WITH YOUR OWN JPG FILE
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 2;
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myJpgPath, options);
  jpgView.setImageBitmap(bm); 
  ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jpgview);
  view.setOnTouchListener(this);

  // ...
  // Work around a Cupcake bug
  matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
  view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
 }

   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
      WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);
      // ...
      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

      // Dump touch event to log
      dumpEvent(event);

      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
         mode = DRAG;
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
         oldDist = spacing(event);
         Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
         if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
         }
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
         mode = NONE;
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                  event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
         }
         break;
      }

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
   }

   /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
   private void dumpEvent(WrapMotionEvent event) {
      // ...
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int action = event.getAction();
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
         sb.append("(pid ").append(
               action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
         sb.append(")");
      }
      sb.append("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
         sb.append("#").append(i);
         sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
         sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
         sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
         if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
      }
      sb.append("]");
      Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
   }

   /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
   private float spacing(WrapMotionEvent event) {
      // ...
      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }

   /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
   private void midPoint(PointF point, WrapMotionEvent event) {
      // ...
      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you consider using a `WebView` and use its built-in zooming capabilities?

Comment: I can't say why the pinch isn't working, but assuming this is the whole code it's using a fixed sample size of 2, so when you zoom in you won't see the detail of the image. I've written a library that loads high resolution tiles as you zoom in, it might help you. https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view